# How to bind non-dependency Text property to Application.Current.Resources?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

How to bind non-dependency Text property to Application.Current.Resources using XAML?

I want to use the Control in third party dll which has non-dependency Text property and I want to bind the Application.Current.Resources to that property.

It cannot use a DynamicResource extension because it is non-dependency property.

What shoud I do?

Comment: I think the topic should be called "How to bind non-dependency Text property to Application.Current.Resources" which is much more clear about what you really need to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you just want to display the Resources value in the Text property of the third party control, you could wrap the Text property from the third party control in a WPF [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) and bind/use DynamicResource against that.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextWrappedProperty = 
                           DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TextWrapped",
                                 typeof(string), typeof(ThirdPartyControl),
                                 new PropertyMetadata(false, TextWrappedChanged));

public static void SetTextWrapped(DependencyObject obj, string wrapped)
{
    obj.SetValue(TextWrappedProperty, wrapped);
}

public static string GetTextWrapped(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (string)obj.GetValue(TextWrappedProperty);
}

private static void TextWrappedChanged(DependencyObject obj, 
                                             DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // here obj will be the third party control so cast to that type
    var thirdParty = obj as ThirdPartyControl;

    // and set the value of the non dependency text property
    if (thirdParty != null)
        thirdParty.Text = e.NewValue;
}
```

Comment: How to Register AttachedProperty to Multiple controls? Because in third party dll has many controls which has Text property. Can I create a method for Register AttachedProperty for them?

Comment: @Noppol is the Text property declared by a common base control type in the third party library? if so specify this common base type in the attached property definition

Comment: The Text property is not declared by a base control. What is the best way to attach property to controls?

Comment: So, I cannot cat obj to ThidPartyControl (var thirdParty = obj as ThirdPartyControl; ). It cannot case DependencyObject to my type.

Comment: What is the type that defines the Text property? this is the type you should specify as the 3rd argument to the `DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached` call, and this is also the type that you should be casting the obj parameter of `TextWrappedChanged` to. I have just used `ThirdPartyControl` as an example and it should be replaced with the type you require.

Comment: Ok, so what place I should paste this code? Is in App.xaml.cs? and the third party control is not derive to DependencyObject, Is it still use attached property?

Comment: You can define the attached property in any place you want. Best idea is to create a new class which is named similar to the third party control you are defining the attached property for. The location it is declared will determine how it is used, so if for example you placed the definition in a class called MyThirdPartyControl, the xaml declaring your control will also declare the attached property as `myNamespace:MyThirdPartyControl.TextWrapped={DynamicResource TextToBindTo}`

Comment: I got "TypeInitializationException" when this piece of codes are execute.